# pass dynamic value in wso2 esb using proxy or sequence

Tags: wso2, esb

I have Url, in the url i have to get the tokenId value
example
 then i have to pass that token id(89047446udhdhd89047446) value to display another list.
Any one help me how to pass the dynamic value to another sequence ?
Give me some example ? 
Thanks before

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use property mediator to pass values between sequences or store/retrieve values.
Here are some useful guides.

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Property+Mediator

[2]http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/03/accessing-various-information-of.html

[3] http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Message+Mediation+Samples

And to pick a value from the request URL, for example to get "To' header

Comment: Hi thanks for your immediate reply. But I am passing dynamic value then i have to store the propertiy mediator. Can you give me some example ?

Comment: One more question wsdl file is necessary to create to connection insequence and outsequence process ? give me example